# C++ bracket format on a new line in vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, format

So, I want my code to look like this:

```
void function()
{
//code
}
```

instead of:

```
void function(){
//code
}
```

I searched a bit and don't quite understand what I did in settings, so I just reset all the settings and I want to make VS Code format like that...

Comment: What's stopping you from doing it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to download extension C/C++ then click right in your file then Format Document With.. then choose C/C++ after all that press Shift + Alt + F

Comment: Can you specify a bit? I have already downloaded the extension, which file do I right click?
I pressed Ctrl + Shift + P and clicked Format Document With... and chose C/C++, then I did what you said but nothing happened...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).